# TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined

Tags: heroku, deployment, build, vercel

So, since yesterday I've started getting the following build errors when attempting to deploy my project to either Heroku or Now. Locally, the project works completely fine. What's the issue here and how do I resolve it?

On Now the logs read as follows:

```html
02/04 10:38 AM (7m)
Error: static/chunks/commons.2ab19e066e0721785714.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at minify (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/minify.js:162:59)
    at TaskRunner.boundWorkers (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:62:41)
    at enqueue (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:82:14)
    at tryCatcher (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:794:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:752:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:729:5)
    at Function.buildError (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:111:14)
    at results.forEach (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:255:50)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at taskRunner.run (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:242:17)
    at step (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:76:9)
    at done (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:84:30)
    at boundWorkers (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:89:13)
    at TaskRunner.boundWorkers (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:64:11)
    at enqueue (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/TaskRunner.js:82:14)
    at tryCatcher (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/tmp/3d5396dc/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9) Error: static/runtime/webpack-42652fa8b82c329c0559.js from Terser
```

And on Heroku they read as:

```html
2019-02-04T10:58:23.286953+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:23:31)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.286955+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:1337:18)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.286956+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:23:31) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287670+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'graphql-tools'
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287672+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287674+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287675+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287676+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287678+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/index.js:2110:18)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287679+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/index.js:23:31)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287680+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/index.js:341:31)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287681+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/index.js:23:31)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287682+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/index.js:1337:18)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287683+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/index.js:23:31)
2019-02-04T10:58:23.287772+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 133)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314730+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: Cannot find module 'graphql-tools'
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314741+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314743+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314745+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314746+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314748+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:2110:18)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314750+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:23:31)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314752+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:341:31)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314753+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:23:31)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314755+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:1337:18)
2019-02-04T10:59:23.314756+00:00 app[web.1]:     at __webpack_require__ (/app/.next/server/static/KANAUI~IRZ6dj1SV~XfmF/pages/_app.js:23:31) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed a short time ago:

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin/issues/66

The reason why it worked locally is because you might have had the old version still cached.